# Why does value_counts not show all values present?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas 0.18.1 on a large dataframe. I am confused by the behaviour of `value_counts()`. This is my code:

```
print df.phase.value_counts()
def normalise_phase(x):
    print x
    return int(str(x).split('/')[0])
df['phase_normalised'] = df['phase'].apply(normalise_phase)
```

This prints the following:

```
2      35092
3      26248
1      24646
4      22189
1/2     8295
2/3     4219
0       1829
dtype: int64
1
nan
```

Two questions:

- Why is `nan` printing as an output of `normalise_phase`, when `nan`
  is not listed as a value in `value_counts`?
- Why does `value_counts` show `dtype` as `int64` if it has string values like
  `1/2` and `nan` in it too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass `dropna=False` for NaNs to be tallied (see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)).
`int64` is the dtype of the series (counts of the values). The values themselves are the index. dtype of the index will be object, if you check.

```
ser = pd.Series([1, '1/2', '1/2', 3, np.nan, 5])

ser.value_counts(dropna=False)
Out: 
1/2    2
5      1
3      1
1      1
NaN    1
dtype: int64

ser.value_counts(dropna=False).index
Out: Index(['1/2', 5, 3, 1, nan], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that `value_counts` dropped `NaN` values, that feels quite unintuitive.

Comment: @Richard In basic operations the default behaviour of pandas is to ignore NaNs (for example when taking the sum. numpy returns nan in that case). I guess in value_counts NaNs are dropped to be consistent but I agree, I was surprised when I first realized that too.